# Find in Page - easier way in Chrome?

Tags: iphone, ios, google-chrome

Is there an Easier way to search for specific words on websites using Chrome on iPhone?
(I know about the “Find in Page” feature accessible from the bottom right. But I’m looking for a ‘one-step’ way to search, similar to Safari)

Comment: Can't you just type the word in the address bar and select 'find in page' from the bottom of the dropdown (like it does in Safari)?

Comment: @fsb How do you do that?  I type a word in Safari address bar  but can't find the "find on page" option.

Comment: In iOS Safari you just type in the search bar and at the [bottom of the results is 'On This Page"](https://www.macrumors.com/how-to/search-specific-text-safari-iphone-ipad/).  I was asking if this is the same in chrome (I don't use google products).